# Is it safe to store persistent data into /var/app_name/

Tags: filesystems

I want to create a system-wide directory, that contains application specific (read-write) data (like log files, configurations and other app specific metadata).

After reading a bit more about the Linux file system, I thought about using `/var/app_name/`, but then I found out, that some of the subdirs are temporary (not persistent among restarts, like `run`, `log`, `tmp`).

How significant is this? I mean, should I use another directory (like `/home/app_name/`) or using `/var/app_name/` is OK?

Comment: In the case of temporary directories it is important to check your OS for `tmpfs` filesystems. By running the `mount` command without arguments it should print a list of filesystems on your machine, including the filesystem type, source, and mount point. If you see any filesystems mounted as `type tmpfs` that means anything written within that mount point will be lost on reboot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY):

> Applications must generally not add directories to the top level of /var. Such directories should only be added if they have some system-wide implication, and in consultation with the FHS mailing list.

You should use `/etc/app_name/` to store config files and other stuff for your program, and `/var/log/app_name/` to store its logfiles.

For the data used by the application, you can store:

- in `/var/lib/app_name/` the persistent data and metadata
- in `/var/cache/app_name/` any app cache that can safely be deleted
- in `/var/spool/app_name/` the data that awaits processing

Definitely **do not use** `/home/app_name/` which is reserved to the homedir of user *app_name*. If your program needs to create a specific user to run as, that'll be its place.

About your question in the comment: Linux does not delete neither rotate logs automatically for anything you put into `/var/log/`. In fact, often sysadmins have the opposite problem of logs filling up all the space... So it's up to you to delete or rotate logfiles; this is done via `logrotate` or a custom cron job.

Comment: Hmm, ok about the logs and configs, but what about the rest of the metadata, that I want to write? That's what's bugging me, the configs and logs are kinda clear. For example, what if I want to store some DB files, where to write them? (thanks for the `/var/log` explanation, btw)

Comment: @KirilKirov Take a look in `/var/lib/` many services/applications store data there. Big one that stands out is `ldap`, an `ldap-server` stores the `ldap` database in `/var/lib/ldap/` by default. `yum` also keeps a `yumdb` in `/var/lib/yum/`

Comment: You could use `/var/lib/app_name/`. I'm adding that to my answer.

Comment: @Centimane Your comment beat mine of a few seconds :)

Comment: I would suggest not to use `/home/app_name` even if the program requires a specific user. If the program requires a specific user, that users shell should be `/sbin/nologin`, and their home directory should either be `/` (to indicate the user does nothing special in their home directory) or `/var/lib/app_name` (in case it is used to direct to the application data). You can look at some of the accounts in `/etc/passwd` for an idea.

Answer (score 1):

It ought to be safe to use `/var/app_name` to store persistent data for an application called `app_name`.

On the system I'm using at the moment, the default database directories for PostgreSQL and MySQL (MariaDB) are `/var/postgresql` and `/var/mysql`, for example.

`/var/tmp` should only be used for temporary files, but a system is unlikely clear this directory out (on reboots, for example, unlike `/tmp`).  `/var/run` is most often used to store PID files and named sockets.

I would avoid `/home/app_name` as `/home` is most often associated with personal account directories.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

An application may choose to store its configuration file in `/etc`, its log files under `/var/log`, and data in `/var/app_name`. In the case of PostgreSQL and MariaDB that I used as examples above, they store everything except system startup hooks in `/var`.

Comment: Does Linux purge logs periodically? My concerns are - if I use `/var/log/`, will the OS delete some of my logs at some point?

Comment: @KirilKirov Specific logs are rotated. It may depend on the distribution, but I don't think there's any Linux that blindly just rotates _everything_ in `/var/log`.